# Inequalites with complex module

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{C}$ such that for all  $z\in B(0_\mathbb{C},1)$ and $|az^2+bz+c|\leq 1$. Proof $$|cz^2+bz+a|\leq 1$$
I tried to use the Maximum modulus principle with $$cz^2+bz+a - (az^2+bz+c)=(c-a)z^2+(c-a) $$
or with the sum $$cz^2+bz+a + (az^2+bz+c)=(a+c)z^2+2bz+(a+c)$$

But idk what else I can do. Please some hint C:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have$$|az^2+bz+c|\leqslant1\tag1$$when $|z|<1$, it follows from the maximum modulus principle $(1)$ holds for any $z\in S^1$. But $z\mapsto\frac1z$ is a bijection from $S^1$ into itself, and therefore$$(\forall z\in S^1):\left|\frac a{z^2}+\frac bz+c\right|\leqslant1,$$which (since $z\in S^1\iff|z|=1$) is equivalent to$$(\forall z\in S^1):|cz^2+bz+a|\leqslant1.$$And then, again by the maximum modulus principle, the inequality $|cz^2+bz+a|\leqslant1$ holds when $|z|<1$.

Comment: Sorry, but idk how to use the MMP, when $|z|<1$, maybe another hint?

Comment: By the maximum modulus theorem, if you have $|cz^2+bz+a|\leqslant1$ for each $z$ such that $|z|=1$, then that inequality also holds when $|z|\leqslant1$, sin the maximum of $|cz^2+bz+a|\leqslant1$ must be attained at the boundary of the closed unit disk.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q(z)=z^{2} p(\frac 1 z)=a+bz+cz^{2}$ where $p(z)=az^{2}+bz+c$. [ Take $ q(0)=a$]
Note that $|p(z)| \leq 1$ when $|z|=1$ (by continuity). Hence, $|q(z)| \leq 1$ when $|z|=1$. By MMP we get $|q(z)| \leq 1$ for $|z| \leq 1$.